# How to configure IIS to accept smart card login from my users across the internet

Tags: asp.net, iis, smartcard, smartcard-reader

Please how can i set up my IIS to accept smart card login from my users across the internet.

i have smart card readers deployed to my client sites - ACR-122-U readers.

each client will be required to simply swipe his/her Mifare ID card to gain access to the website.

how do i begin to setup such a scenario in ASP.net on IIS.

Please i do not want to use ActiveX -- the solution should work from any browser, not just IE.

thanks.

Comment: when u swipe any card it returns value, u just pass that parsed value to page through querystring. then u just authenticate value & access ur website

Comment: how do i get the value from the smart card that was swiped?

Comment: i assumed that it may be similar like cc card swiper, sorry i dont have any idea about  ACR-122-U readers....:(

Comment: does your credit card swiper come with a vendor library or is it just plug-and-play compatible? Also, how do you get the return value from the card you swiped... so you can pass it on to your website?

Comment: no it is just plug & play, it returns data in format of track1 track2 data whch is raw format. yes so we pass it on a webservice